# How to update table with dynamic column names?

Tags: sql-server-2012

The update statement below works as intended. However, I need to loop the statement upwards of 50 times. I'm trying to write a loop that will allow me to change the field that is getting set from Seg1 to SegX and the update the SubString(GoalBusinessSegment,(6*1)-5,5) AS 'Seg' to SubString(GoalBusinessSegment,(6*X)-5,5) AS 'Seg'

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST]
SET Seg1 = SegTBL.Seg
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GoalBusinessSegment,SubString(GoalBusinessSegment,(6*1)-5,5) AS 'Seg'
      FROM [2017].[dbo].[WPGDM]
      WHERE GoalID BETWEEN 22.1 AND 22.4 AND 
            LEFT(GoalBusinessSegment,1) = 'B' AND LEN(GoalBusinessSegment) > 5
     ) SegTBL
WHERE [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST].SegID = SegTBL.GoalBusinessSegment
```

Below is my attempt at the loop.

```
DECLARE @LoopCount int
DECLARE @SegField varchar(255)
DECLARE @i int

DELETE FROM [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST]

INSERT INTO     [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST]
SELECT DISTINCT GoalBusinessSegment AS 'SegID'
            ,NULL AS 'Seg1'
            ,NULL AS 'Seg2'
            ,NULL AS 'Tgt1'
            ,NULL AS 'Tgt2'
            ,NULL AS 'Act1'
            ,NULL AS 'Act2'
FROM        [2017].[dbo].[WPGDM]
WHERE       GoalID BETWEEN 22.1 AND 22.4 AND LEFT(GoalBusinessSegment,1) = 'B' AND LEN(GoalBusinessSegment) > 5

Set @LoopCount = (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(LEN(GoalBusinessSegment))/5)
                  FROM [2017].[dbo].[WPGDM]
                 )
WHILE @i <= @LoopCount 
BEGIN
Set @SegField = 'Seg' + @LoopCount
UPDATE [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST]
  SET @SegField = SegTBL.Seg
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GoalBusinessSegment
            ,SubString(GoalBusinessSegment,(6*@i)-5,5) AS 'Seg'
            FROM [2017].[dbo].[WPGDM]
            WHERE GoalID BETWEEN 22.1 AND 22.4 AND LEFT(GoalBusinessSegment,1) = 'B' AND LEN(GoalBusinessSegment) > 5
       ) SegTBL
 WHERE [dbo].[MULTBUSSEGTEST].SegID = SegTBL.GoalBusinessSegment
 SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

The loop produces all null values, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that multiple fields and the update statement were not necessary. Problem solved.